# How to insert all information data (text) from StringBuilder into one row in .csv file

Tags: java, csv, row

When we use StringBuilder to save data that is read from a text file, we use `\n` to catch line.
Then I save this data into a .csv file and, because of `\n`, this data will be inserted into multiple rows in the .csv file.

However, our target is to save all data into a single row in the .csv file. Please let me know how.

(Note: Using Java (SWT), HSSWorkBook)

Comment: Not sure how are you reading file into StringBuilder, while reading you can replace all `\n` character or you can replace using `indexof`  and `replace` methods of StringBuilder

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CSVWriter there are constructors which allow you to define a different line end character (maybe | or something).

http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/au/com/bytecode/opencsv/CSVWriter.html